# SVG attributes and properties

Tags: css, inheritance, svg, properties, attributes

Below is two example-specifications:

### [**Rect: X-attribute**](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/shapes.html#RectElementXAttribute)

> **x = "(coordinate)."**
>
> The x-axis coordinate of the side of the rectangle
> which has the smaller x-axis coordinate value in the current user
> coordinate system.
> ***If the attribute is not specified, the effect is as
> if a value of "0" were specified.***
>
> *Animatable: yes.*

### [Color-property](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/color.html#ColorProperty)

> **‘color’**
>
> **Value:**    (color) | inherit
>
> **Initial:**      depends on user agent
>
> **Applies to:** elements to which properties ‘fill’, ‘stroke’, ‘stop-color’, ‘flood-color’ and ‘lighting-color’ apply
>
> **Inherited:** yes
>
> **Percentages:** N/A
>
> **Media:** visual
>
> **Animatable:** yes

It seems that some `attributes` are called `properties`. What are the differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some SVG attributes are actually [mapped CSS properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/propidx.html). That is to say when you write what looks like an attribute such as fill="blue" that's actually CSS you're defining.

Some CSS properties are inherited by default, some arent't. fill is an inherited CSS property as you've discovered. Properties that are not inherited are called reset properties, to get a reset property to inherit you'd have to explicitly set it as inherit on all the descendent elements.

Some things are not CSS properties at all though, they are simply attributes. Attributes do not inherit at all, although their effects may apply to their children if the attribute's description explicitly says so e.g. like the x and y attribute values apply to the children of `<text>` elements.

In SVG 1.1 x and y are generally attributes, in SVG 2 they are usually CSS properties.

There are no attributes that do not have an explicit default value (otherwise browsers would not be able to have interoperable implementations).

CSS properties have default values too (they are called initial values). The [initial value for fill is black](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillProperties) for instance.

Nothing ever throws, there's always a default or initial value.

Comment: Well this clears up things alot. So basically some attributes can be declared in multiple ways: 1. Inside element as attributes. 2. Inside element's 'style'-attribute as CSS properties. 3. In external or internal CSS document with: 'class'-attribute, 'id'-attribute, or styling with element's name f.ex: circle { fill: red }.